# Sending an Array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a PHP array called $json that I decoded from my .txt file. It has information laid out like this:

[image]

I'm trying to send the [email] and [fullname] to my database using PHP. I'm confused how to actually add the $json array to my code. I've been successful in adding the sample data but when replacing the `add(array(`my code breaks. Can anyone give me a tip on how to pursue further?

```
$url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/form/test.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content,true);
str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_decode($json), ENT_NOQUOTES));
$auth = array(
'api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$wrap = new CS_REST_Subscribers('xxxxxxxxx', $auth);
$result = $wrap->add(array(
'EmailAddress' => "thisisatest@gmail.com",
'Name' => "john",
'CustomFields' => array(
    array(
        'Key' => 'Field 1 Key',
        'Value' => 'Field Value'
    ),
    array(
        'Key' => 'Field 2 Key',
        'Value' => 'Field Value'
    ),
    array(
        'Key' => 'Multi Option Field 1',
        'Value' => 'Option 1'
    ),
    array(
        'Key' => 'Multi Option Field 1',
        'Value' => 'Option 2'
    )
),
'Resubscribe' => true
));
```

Comment: and note that there's no such thing as a "json array". there's only a json string, which may CONTAIN the textual representation of an array. but json is just a string. you never deal with json directly. json's a transport/encoding format. you decode the json into a native structure (a php array, e.g.) and deal with that array directly, then RE-encode to json once you're done.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying. Yes it is a json string that has the structure of an array. It breaks when I try and replace $wrap->add($json. Just a 404 error the page refuses to load. I assumed this was the correct notation but can't find any documentation on using json strings.

Comment: well, if `add()` is expecting a php array, then passing in a json string is not going to work. but your picture is not a "json array". it's a var_dump of a php array.nowhere in your code do you actually have json.

Comment: edit: @MarcB so if my picture is a php array and it's expecting a php array, do you have any documentation on how I can proceed?

I decoded the json string up at the top from a .txt file.

Comment: Is there a way that you could make the font in the image any smaller?

Comment: @AbraCadaver apologies, i didn't want to cut anything out. the real image link is here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/phdRD.png

Comment: What's the output of `echo $json[0]['email'];` ?

Comment: @maxhb It gives me the correct e-mail. Sending $json[0][email] works successfully in sending the one entry. I actually tried to do a for loop but I get a blank page. http://i.imgur.com/W0P6nEz.png